# Trying to connect to a remote JVM through JConsole

Tags: java, jvm, jconsole

I'm trying to connect to a remote JVM on a Linux box from JConsole on a Windows machine. I've made sure the ports (default ports 9102 and 9202) are open. Trying to connect immediately throws up a ConnectionFailedSSL1 ConnectionFailedSSL2. No other errors. I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong or if I'm missing a step.

Comment: Better mention the application servers rather than the OS. What application server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access remotely to the JMX server, you have to declare the associated system properties:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

You may need to set the property `com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate` to `true` but then you would have to add below authentication ones:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=path/to/jmxremote.password
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=path/to/jmxremote.access
```

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to set those in the JAVA_OPTS system variable?

Comment: There should be exported as commandline arguments, but a good approach to follow is to set those into the *$CATALINA_OPTS* properties if you are using Apache Tomcat or any other property holder such as *$JAVA_OPTS*.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to have to do a little more digging. That didn't seem to work. I can still connect using "Insecure" when I get the error. The log file for jconsole says "Expecting a javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIClientSocketFactory RMI client socket factory in stub!"